# Please help me simplify this jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I know that a good portion of this jQuery code is unnecessary, especially in the repetition of the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` events.

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
         $(function(){
              $('.panel').hide();

              $('.work_button').click(function(){
                    $('#cms,#contact').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('#work').fadeIn();
                    });
              });

              $('.cms_button').click(function(){
                    $('#work,#contact').fadeOut(function(){
                          $('#cms').fadeIn();
                    });
              });

              $('.contact_button').click(function(){
                    $('#cms,#work').fadeOut(function(){
                          $('#contact').fadeIn();
                    });
              });

              $('.home_button').click(function(){
                    $('.panel:visible').fadeOut();
              });
        });
    </script>

<div class="menu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="home_button">home</li>
<li class="work_button">work</li>
<li class="cms_button">cms</a></li>
<li class="contact_button">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

    <div class="panel" id="work">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel" id="cms">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel" id="contact">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: This sort of question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll head over there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would name the buttons with the same class name as the panel ID:

```
<button class="home">Home</button>
<button class="work">Work</button>
<button class="cms">CMS</button>
<button class="contact">Contact</button>

<div class="panel" id="home">
    <p>..Home..</p>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="work">
    <p>..work..</p>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="cms">
    <p>..cms..</p>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="contact">
    <p>..contact..</p>
</div>​
```

Then you can simplify your script ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/q4NUN/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('.panel').hide();

    $('button').click(function(){
        var tar = $(this).attr('class'); // replace "_button" if there
        $('.panel').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#' + tar).fadeIn();
        });

    });

});​
```

---

If asked how I would make the menu work, I would do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/q4NUN/1/):

```
$(function() {
    $('.panel:not(#home)').hide();

    $('.menu li').click(function() {
        var tar = '#' + $(this).attr('class').replace("_button",'');
        $('.panel:not(' + tar + ')').fadeOut();
        $(tar).fadeIn();
    });

});​
```

Comment: There are no 'buttons.' Anything that has an element named 'button' is actually a link. And the demo acts wonky.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by wonky... if you mean the way it fades in and out, I just copied the method you used. If you want to know how I would do it, check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/q4NUN/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
      $('.panel').hide();

      $('.work_button,.cms_button,.home_button').click(function(){
            var thiss=$(this);
            $('.panel').fadeOut(function(){
            thiss.fadeIn();
            });
      });
      $('.home_button').click(function(){
            $('.panel:visible').fadeOut();
      });

});
```

Comment: This won't work because the `$(this)` inside the click function targets all of the panels (the `this` from the `fadeOut`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
       $('.panel').hide();
        $('.work_button').click(function(){
             FadeOutIn($('#cms,#contact'), $('#work'));
        });
        $('.cms_button').click(function(){
             FadeOutIn($('#work,#contact'), $('#cms'));
        });
        $('.contact_button').click(function(){
             FadeOutIn($('#cms,#work'), $('#contact'));
        });
        $('.home_button').click(function(){
             FadeOutIn($('.panel:visible'), null));
        });
    });

    function FadeOutIn(fadeOutElements, fadeInElements) {
       fadeOutElements.fadeOut(function(){
             fadeInElements.fadeIn();
       });
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery UI, that'll make live easier!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#panels').accordion();
    });
</script>

<div id="#panels">
    <h3><a href="#">Work</a></h3>
    <div class="panel" id="work">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="#">CMS</a></h3>
    <div class="panel" id="cms">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="#">Contact</a></h3>
    <div class="panel" id="contact">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't want an accordion, I wanted the divs to fade in and out. The code works, I just wanted to simplify it.